# Identifying and fixing css library clashes

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, materialize

I am trying to combine a tooltip with a horizontal FAB, from the [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) library. However, the outcome is being corrupted by another library, or some of my site's custom css (I am using angular2 so there are a few different css files). You can see the specific issue below, but I wondered how I can approach finding which css rules in which file are corrupting the default materialize behaviour. At the end of the question you can see my approach to date.

In the following code, the end action icon of the FAB should display a hovering tooltip below it:

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal" style="bottom: calc(100% - 80px); right: 24px;">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
        <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
    </a>
    <ul>
       <li><a class="btn-floating red tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am tooltip"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
       <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
       <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
       <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

However, the tooltip message seems to replace the contents of the action icon?

[image]

I am assuming that there is a clash between materialize and some other js/css on my site. By forcing `overflow: display`, I can get this result:

[image]

So now the issue us a colouring and positioning one? Any ideas what properties are likely to be corrupting this, or how I could find them. I targetted the element in Chrome Dev tools, but there wasn't any obvious cause and I couldn't inspect the actual tooltip, only the underlying button.

Comment: I just created a pen and it's working fine for me. http://codepen.io/T-P/pen/vXmJOQ